# What's the difference between $\nabla \cdot \vec{u}$, $\vec{u} \cdot \nabla$, $\nabla \vec{u}$ and $\vec{u} \nabla$?

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis

If context is needed, a lot of these notations appear in [this deal.II tutorial](https://dealii.org/9.2.0/doxygen/deal.II/step_8.html), and I have a hard time telling which ones are equivalent to each other and which ones are not. So if someone could sum up the commonalities and differences of these four variations, it would help me out a great deal.

1. $\nabla \cdot \vec{u}$
2. $\vec{u} \cdot \nabla$
3. $\nabla \vec{u}$
4. $\vec{u} \nabla$

Comment: If $u = (u_{1}(x,y,z,t), u_{2}(x,y,z,t), u_{3}(x,y,z,t))$ then
\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot u &= \partial_{x} u_{1} + \partial_{y} u_{2} + \partial_{z} u_{3} \\
u \cdot \nabla &= u_{1} \partial_{x} + u_{2} \partial_{y} + u_{3} \partial_{z} \\
\nabla u &= \begin{pmatrix} \partial_{x} u_{1} & \partial_{y} u_{1} & \partial_{z} u_{1} \\ \partial_{x} u_{2} & \partial_{y} u_{2} & \partial_{z} u_{2} \\ \partial_{x} u_{3} & \partial_{y} u_{3} & \partial_{z} u_{3} 
\end{pmatrix}^{T}
\end{align}

Comment: @mattos Thanks! So unless I'm missing something, basically 1 = 2? Don't get what's going on with 3, are you assuming $\nabla u$ is the outer product ($\nabla \otimes u$)?

Comment: 1 is not 2 since 1 is a scalar and 2 is a linear differential operator.

Comment: @Paul Ah that explains a lot. So opposed to 1, 2 has to be followed by something to turn into a numerical value and doesn't really make sense on its own?

Comment: Yes that is right, 2 is a linear combination of the derivative operators which might arise as a change of basis for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short summary based on the comments and some info I found in a book:

1. $\nabla \cdot \vec{u}$ is the divergence of the vector field.
2. $\vec{u} \cdot \nabla$ is a linear differential operator (completely different type of object than $\nabla \cdot \vec{u}$).
3. $\nabla \vec{u}$ is the gradient of the vector field (more clearly written as $\nabla\otimes\vec{u}$, with $\otimes$ being the tensor product).
4. $\vec{u} \nabla$ is the transposed gradient of the vector field ($\vec{u} \nabla$=$\nabla \vec{u}^T$)